# How to eliminate nulls grouping when using group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query that I need to sum all the related sale price to a certain org and Id but since there's some nulls, the group by is not acting the way I expect it.
I need every sale go to its own id, org and disregard the nulls instead of grouping it. I created this sample which is similar to what I'm facing.

```
create table TempTest(id int, org varchar(10),SoldPrice int);
insert into TempTest values(1,'OR100',50);
insert into TempTest values(1,'OR100',25);
insert into TempTest values(1,null,25);
insert into TempTest values(2,'OR200',100);
insert into TempTest values(2,'null',100);
insert into TempTest values(3,'OR300',100);
insert into TempTest values(3,null,100);
insert into TempTest values(3,'OR300',100);
```

I need every sale go to its own id, org and ignoring the nulls instead of grouping it
expected output requested is:
1,'OR100',100

while what I'm getting with id 1 is like this

[image]

so its not bringing any row that has nulls in org, how can I overcome that?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please show us your query!

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for `group by`?

```
select id, max(org), sum(soldprice)
from temptest
group by id;
```